# Determine transformation matrix of linear map in respect to monomial basis.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I'am having a hard time trying to understand the following task.

Consider the function: $\ell : \mathcal{P}_{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{ll}{\qquad \ell\left(\sum_{k=0}^{2} a_{k} m_{k}\right) :=\left(\begin{array}{cc}{2 a_{0}+0 a_{1}+0 a_{2}} & {-2 a_{0}+0 a_{1}+3 a_{2}} \\ {-2 a_{0}+0 a_{1}-6 a_{2}} & {0 a_{0}+0 a_{1}+0 a_{2}}\end{array}\right)}\end{array}
\end{equation}

Determine the transformation matrix $\ell_{\mathcal{B} \leftarrow \mathcal{M}_{2}}$ for the monomial basis: $\mathcal{M}_{2}=\left(\mathbf{m}_{0}, \mathbf{m}_{1}, \mathbf{m}_{2}\right)$ and the standard basis:
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{l} {\qquad \mathcal{B}=\left(\left(\begin{array}{cc}{1} & {0} \\ {0} & {0}\end{array}\right),\left(\begin{array}{cc}{0} & {1} \\ {0} & {0}\end{array}\right),\left(\begin{array}{cc}{0} & {0} \\ {1} & {0}\end{array}\right),\left(\begin{array}{cc}{0} & {0} \\ {0} & {1}\end{array}\right)\right)}\end{array}
\end{equation}

So the first thing I do is putting $\mathcal{M}_{2}$ into $\ell$.

Then we obtain this for $\ell\left(m_{0}\right)$:
\begin{equation}
\ell\left(m_{0}\right)=\ell\left(1 m_{0}+0 m_{1}+0 m_{2}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}{2} & {-2} \\ {-2} & {0}\end{array}\right)
\end{equation}

and for $m_{1},m_{2}=$ $\left(\begin{array}{cc}{0} & {0} \\ {0} & {0}\end{array}\right),\left(\begin{array}{cc}{0} & {3} \\ {-6} & {0}\end{array}\right)$

This is probably trivial but I just don't understand what happens next. The solution to this task is:

\begin{equation}
\ell_{\mathcal{B} \leftarrow \mathcal{M}_{2}}=
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}{2} & {0} & {0} \\ {-2} & {0} & {3} \\ {-2} & {0} & {-6} \\ {0} & {0} & {0}\end{array}\right)
\end{equation}

Can someone explain why I can write the matrices I obatained into vectors (i.e $\left(\begin{array}{cc}{2} & {-2} \\ {-2} & {0}\end{array}\right) $ as $\begin{equation}
\left(\begin{array}{c}{2} \\ {-2} \\ {-2} \\ {0}\end{array}\right)
\end{equation}$)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is simply because$$\begin{bmatrix}2&-2\\-2&0\end{bmatrix}=2\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}-2\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}-2\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{bmatrix}+0\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: So all what is done is expressing $\begin{equation}
\left[\begin{array}{cc}{2} & {-2} \\ {-2} & {0}\end{array}\right]
\end{equation}$ as linear combination of the basis $\mathcal{B}$ and therefore we obtain $\ell_{\mathcal{B} \leftarrow \mathcal{M}_{2}}$?

Can I obtain the information that $\ell_{\mathcal{B} \leftarrow \mathcal{M}_{2}}$'s matrix representation has to be $\mathbb{R}^{4 \times 3}$ because we have 4 bases in $\mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{M}_{2}$ consists out of 3 entries (i.e $\left(\begin{array}{c}{1} \\ {x} \\ {x^2}\end{array}\right)$)?

Comment: No. It's because $\dim\mathcal P_2=3$ and $\dim\mathbb R^{2\times2}=4$.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you.